# How to process an exception during show randering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have following code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  show 'rows' do
    columns do
      panel t("activerecord.models.booking.other") do
        table_for resource.bookings do
          column :from
          column :to
          column :start_at_with_timezone
          column :ticket_till
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I have some issue with `bookings` it can be nil, or some issue with `booking`'s properties, how I can use [rescue](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/rescue.html)?

UPD: in real code, I have the complex logic, some times it had broken, and I want to render this exception, without rails exception web form, because in production mode users gets 500 HTTP error.

Comment: what do you mean with `[rescue][1]` ?

Comment: @MohamedZiata I updated, I mean use begin ... rescue ... end for process exeption

Comment: Perhaps rails' [rescue_from](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) will be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then use [`rescue_from`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from). Like this:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  controller do
    rescue_from MyErrorClass, with: :handle_my_error_class

    private

    def handle_my_error_class
      render 'layout/404.html' # or something
    end
  end

  show 'rows' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand your problem `resource.bookings` returns an `Array` that can contain `nil` as value. Example:

```rb
resource.bookings # => [<Booking id=23>, nil, <Booking id=52>]
```

Then change `resource.bookings` for `resource.bookings.compact` this way the `nil` values will be removed.

```rb
resource.bookings.compact # => [<Booking id=23>, <Booking id=52>]
```

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation of my problem I updated the issue, your solution is a good only for this one case.